# QLogic Fiber Card not working with HYVE-Zeus Server

Tags: nic, windows-server-2019, fiber

I have a QLogic QLE2564 Fiber Card that doesn’t seem to be working with my server. I am running windows server 2019 on a Hyve Zeus V1 with a supermicro X9DRD-LF motherboard. When installed, the card is not detected in device manager or when the system boots. All the lights on the card remain on even after boot. I have the card installed in the only pcie slot on the board with a riser. I tested it without the riser and still get the same results. I disabled the onboard gig ports through the bios and rebooted. That did nothing. I don’t have another machine to test the card itself. Is there something in the bios I’m missing or needs a flash? Is the card not compatible or could it be dead?

Comment: Given the latest drivers for this FC HBA are for Vista (https://driverdownloads.qlogic.com/QLogicDriverDownloads_UI/SearchByProduct.aspx?ProductCategory=39&Product=1092&Os=163) then I strongly suspect it's not supported in S2019

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "fiber card". The QLE2564 is a *Fibre Channel* HBA/initiator. With an appropriate driver it should show up as *storage controller* in Windows. Drivers for Win2019 seem  to be available [here](https://driverdownloads.qlogic.com/QLogicDriverDownloads_UI/SearchByProduct.aspx?ProductCategory=39&Product=1092&Os=217).

If you're trying to attach Fibre Channel storage that's the right thing. It won't work with any *Ethernet* equipment, however.

Comment: You beat me to it :)